# How can I get the Max function to return a value in the winning cells column but not the winning cell itself?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

```
1. Weeks    22  23  24

2.         3     7   1
3.        4%    9%  1%
4.        4%    2%  2%
```

For example in row 3, how would I get the MAX function to have 9% win but then return the number 23 a row above?

Comment: I'm sorry, what? Do you want row two to show its value in row 1 *if* its row three value is the largest?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that your question is hard to understand; I’m partially guessing what you mean. 
But I believe that what you want is

```
=INDEX(B$1:D$1,  1,  MATCH(MAX($B2:$D2), $B2:$D2, 0))
```

This would be placed somewhere on Row `2` and dragged down.

Explanation:

- You’ve probably already tried `MAX($B2:$D2)` -- find the maximum value in the row.
- `MATCH(`*`MAX`*`, $B2:$D2, 0)` finds the column in the row where the maximum occurs.
- `INDEX(B$1:D$1, 1,` *`column_number`*`)` gets the value from Row `1` at the indicated column number.

Example result:

```
1. Weeks    22    23    24
2.           3     7     1    23
3.          4%    9%    1%    23
4.          4%    2%    2%    22
```

Answer (score 0):

```
9   8   7
    8   
2   4   3
```

The second row has a formula of `=IF(MAX($B$3:$D$3) = B3,B1,"")` that goes in series across.

So:

```
B2 = IF(MAX($B$3:$D$3) = B3,B1,"")
C2 = IF(MAX($B$3:$D$3) = C3,C1,"")
D2 = IF(MAX($B$3:$D$3) = D3,D1,"")
```